# BindParam for inserting multiple values

Tags: php, mysqli

Let's say I have value for user,form,and ownerID. The value for user stays the same however ownerID might vary from time to time.

for example:

```
$user = "Farhana"; // fix value
$form = "Registration"; // fix value
$ownerID = array("23","50","33"); // item in array not fix, may have many ownerID
```

then I want to insert multiple values with single sql statement like this.

```
INSERT INTO messages (user,ownerID,form) VALUES ("Farhana","23","Registration"),("Farhana","50","Registration"),("Farhana","33","Registration");
```

so I have come out with foreach solution but I'm not sure this is correct or not.

```
// prepare
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (user,ownerID,form) VALUES (?,?,?)");
// bind param
foreach ($ownerID as $ID){
    $stmt->bind_param("sss",$user,$ID,$form);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not really important, but just for sake of clarity bind_param have to be called only once.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO messages (user,ownerID,form) VALUES (?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$user,$ID,$form);
foreach ($ownerID as $ID){
    $stmt->execute();
}
```